# using variables of main file in imported file

Tags: python, import-module

I am using python and cannot solve the problem myself. I defined the variables(rb. data) in the 'main file' below. And I imported 'hp file' to use hotplate function. ( i611Robot, Teachdata, MotionParam,Position are included in 'A file' )

```
from hp import *
from A import *

def main():
    rb = i611Robot()
    data = Teachdata()
    m1 = MotionParam(30,20,10,2,2)
    position_1 = Position(100,200,100,0,0,0)
    ...
    ....
    hotplate(rb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the 'hp file' which is imported.

```
from A import *
def hotplate(rb) :
    rb.motionparam( m1 )
    rb.move( position_1 ) 
    .......
```

But the problem is when I play 'main file', it says

```
File "main.py" line.., in <module>
    main()
File "main/py", line ...., in main
    hotplate()
File ".../hotplate.py", in line .., in hotplate
    rb.motionparam( m1 ) 
NameError : global name 'm1' is not defined
```

I already asked question about how to use     rb in     hotplate.py and get answer that I have to put     rb in     hotplate(). This works well.
But another problem is that there are **so many variables, parameters like     rb and     m1,
position_1 that will be used in     hotplate.py file**.
**How can I use those all variables,instances,parameters in     hotplate.py file.**

Comment: A module should not depend on the variables in the script that imports it. Functions should get their information from parameters.

Comment: Is it totally weird way to using some variables like this way? I'm new to python, and I cannot understand what you mean.
There are other modules like hotplate and they will use the same variables made by main.py file. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: A module should be self-contained, it shouldn't be dependent on how the caller is written. Also, `m1` is a local variable in `main()`, it's not visible outside the function, even in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar already commented, functions should get their information from parameters.

### Your code

What you're doing doesn't work:

```
def a():
    myVar = "Hello"
    b()


def b():
    print(myVar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a()
```

The function `b` doesn't know the variable `myVar`, the variable is out of scope.

### Solution

What you have to do is to pass the arguments which the function needs to the function's parameters:

```
def a():
    myVar = "Hello"
    b(myVar)


def b(myArg):
    print(myArg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a()
```

**Output**

```
Hello
```

Learn about python functions here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp